# Issue with importing module from sub subfolder

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make use of the [uncertainty](https://github.com/meyersbs/uncertainty) library and I've cloned the repo in my dir structure that looks like this:

```
.Lux/
├── generateFeatures.py
├── generateLexicons.py
├── __init__.py
├── res
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── test2.py
│   └── uncertainty
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── test1.py
│       └── uncertainty
│           ├── classifier.py
│           ├── lib
│           │   ├── __init.py__
│           │   └── nlp
│           │       ├── __init__.py
```

my two test.py have similar content, and all they try to do is import the uncertainty classifier

test1.py works flawlessly

```
from uncertainty.classifier import Classifier
```

but test2.py

```
from uncertainty.uncertainty.classifier import Classifier
```

yields:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lucas/Lux/Lux/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 359, in get_provider
    module = sys.modules[moduleOrReq]
KeyError: 'uncertainty.lib.nlp'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from uncertainty.uncertainty.classifier import Classifier
  File "/home/lucas/Lux/res/uncertainty/uncertainty/classifier.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .lib.nlp import summarizer
  File "/home/lucas/Lux/res/uncertainty/uncertainty/lib/nlp/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    VERBS_PATH = resource_filename('uncertainty.lib.nlp', 'verbs.txt')
  File "/home/lucas/Lux/Lux/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1144, in resource_filename
    return get_provider(package_or_requirement).get_resource_filename(
  File "/home/lucas/Lux/Lux/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 361, in get_provider
    __import__(moduleOrReq)
ImportError: No module named 'uncertainty.lib'
```

Why does test1.py works and test2.py doesnt?

### Updates

I've placed empty `__init__.py` on every folder that didn't have them, but still can't figure this out.

I've tried renaming my outer `uncertainty` folder to something else thinking it could be a bad resolved name, but that also didn't work.

Comment: It looks like it can't locate `lib.nlp.summarizer`. Have your tried changing `from .lib.nlp import summarizer` to `from uncertainty.uncertainty.lib.nlp import summarizer` ?

Comment: I really don't want to start changing third party code, since I don't know how the authors structured it. But I did just to see what would happen and I get: `ImportError: No module named 'uncertainty.lib'`

Comment: The `uncertainty` repo has a setup.py file, so I would recommend installing it, as you are not interested in modifying the code. This way, your pythonpath will always include `uncertainty`, allowing you to use the package like any other third-party package.

Installation can be achieved through `pip install uncertainty`, see also here: https://github.com/meyersbs/uncertainty/wiki/Installation-&-Usage

Comment: I had already installed it via pip aswell. Deleting the uncertainty folder from my subfolder and just calling the package as any other works perfectly, thank you! 

Still, I would really like to understand why I couldn't import it the way I was trying to do.

Comment: Quick guess: as the line `VERBS_PATH = resource_filename('uncertainty.lib.nlp', 'verbs.txt')` in `uncertainty/lib/nlp/__init__.py` specifies the `uncertainty` folder and the folder from which `test2` is called has an `uncertainty` folder, it will look for the `lib/nlp` folders from there, which is one level too high up in the directory tree. Again, thats just a guess, but it seems logical to me.

Comment: @thom747it makes the whole sense to me as well. Anyways, you've pointed the way to the solution with the last comment, if you want to create an answer with both of your comments combined, I'd be more than happy to accept it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is occurring due to the `__init__.py` file in `lib/nlp` folder. As pointed out by [thom747](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11095579/thom747) in comments, the `VERBS_PATH` provides a path for `verbs'txt` in `uncertainty/lib/nlp`.

This path is correct when you are importing from `test1.py`, but while importing from `test2.py`, it looks for for `lib/nlp` in the parent `uncertainty` directory, where `test2.py` file is present. It cannot find one, hence you are getting an `ImportError`.

**FIX**

Just change `VERBS_PATH` assignment in the `uncertainty/lib/nlp/__init__.py` file as

```
VERBS_PATH = resource_filename('uncertainty.uncertainty.lib.nlp', 'verbs.txt')
```

Comment: This fixt it for test2.py but is not a general fix, is it? If I try to call from a script on the /Lux/ directory would I have to change the path again?

Comment: Yes, you have to again change it. Or, you can also provide absolute path to `verbs.txt` in `lib/nlp/__init__.py`